# Conditions to apply the inverse Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function such that $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$: $t \mapsto e^{\alpha t}f(t) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+)$. Let $\hat{f}(\lambda) := \int_0^\infty{e^{-\lambda t}f(t) dt}$ be its Laplace transform defined for $Re(\lambda) \geq \alpha$.

My question is: what  natural conditions should we add on $f$ such that the inverse Laplace formula holds, that is:
$$ \forall t \geq 0, \forall \sigma > \alpha, f(t) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma - i T}^{\sigma + i T}{e^{zt} \hat{f}(z) dz}$$

What are the standard references on this question?

Answer (score 2):

If $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}|f(t)|dt < \infty$ for some real $\alpha$, then the Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}\{f\}(\lambda)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}f(t)dt$ is defined and continuous for $\Re\lambda \ge \alpha$, and it is holomorphic in the open region as well. The proposed inversion integral is the limit of the following as $R\uparrow\infty$, assuming $\sigma \ge \alpha$:
\begin{align}
    & \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iR}^{\sigma+iR}e^{\lambda x}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}f(t)dt d\lambda \\
   & = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iR}^{\sigma+iR}e^{-\lambda (t-x)}d\lambda f(t)dt \\
   & = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}(e^{-(\sigma+iR)(t-x)}-e^{-(\sigma-iR)(t-x)})f(t)dt \\
   & = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-\sigma(t-x)}\frac{\sin(R(t-x))}{t-x}f(t)dt \\
   & = e^{\sigma x}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(R(t-x))}{t-x}e^{-\sigma t}f(t)dt.
\end{align}
This is a well-known integral from Fourier Analysis. Because $e^{-\alpha t}f(t)$ is absolutely integrable, so is $e^{-\sigma t}f(t)$ because $\sigma \ge \alpha$ by assumption. If $f$ is piecewise smooth, or satisfies other similar Fourier conditions, then the above converges as $R\rightarrow\infty$ to
$$
     e^{\sigma x} \left[e^{-\sigma x}\frac{f(x-0)+f(x+0)}{2}\right].
$$
And that's what you want. And the result does not depend on the choice of $\sigma$, provided $\sigma \ge \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is very useful. What do you mean by $f$ being piecewise smooth? For instance, is $f$ continuous enough? If I understood correctly, the problem can be reduce to the following: if $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\eta_T(x) = T sinc(Tx)$, which regularity on $g$ ensure that: $\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} (g * \eta_T) (x) = g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $*$ denotes the convolution product, right?

Comment: I have question regarding your solution or in general of the inverse Laplace formula.
As you sad we have convergence of the last integral towards $\frac{f(x+0)+f(x-0)}2$, that means for $x=0$ the Laplace inversion formula converges towards $f(0)/2$? 
That means, for a continuous differentiable function of exponential order, the Laplace inversion formula holds everywhere except at $t=0$ ?

Comment: @Salfalur : $f(0+0)/2$, which is half of the right hand limit of $f$ at $0$.